# Auto login for two sites hosted on IIS at two diffrent ports

Tags: c#, session, iis, cookies, asp-classic

I have deployed two instance of same website on IIS on two different ports, one for testing and other for production. When i logged in to production site and after that i am going for logging in to testing site (without logging off the production site), the testing site use same session and do not ask me for username password.
I have same users in both sites.
Can anybody suggest me how can i tackle with this problem.?

Comment: Use host headers in IIS and either add them into DNS or modify your local host file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use in private/incognito browsing for testing. Or use different domains

You can also use a different web browser.

Internet explorer for testing site and Firefox for production

Answer (score 1):

Surprised no one has suggested specifying `Host headers` that way you can use port `80` and both instances will not be confused because the hostname will be different and session cookies will not cross over between instances.

Apart from some configuration in IIS and modifications to your DNS server or just using Local Hosts there is no changes needed to your code or switching browsers. I use this technique all the time, have 10+ sites all running on an IIS Server using same port `80` but different host headers.

### Example

> **IIS Website - www.mysite.com**
>   *Binding configuration, IP address used is purely for example purposes.*
>
> ```
> IP Address: 192.168.1.100
> Host Header: www.mysite.com
> Port: 80
> ```
>
> **Local Host File or DNS**
>   *IP address used is purely for example purposes.*
>
> ```
> 192.168.1.100        www.mysite.com        # Example DNS / Local Host Entry
> ```

---

### Links

- [Configure a Host Header for a Web Site (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

---

### Ish's Example

*Taken from comments below*

> **IIS Website - www.abc.com:85**
>   *Binding configuration*
>
> ```
> IP Address: 127.0.0.1
> Host Header: www.abc.com
> Port: 85
> ```
>
> **Local Host File or DNS**
>   *IP address used is purely for example purposes.*
>
> ```
> 127.0.0.1        www.abc.com        # Ish's Local Host Entry
> ```

Comment: A little bit confused.How can i modify DNS server settings to my localhost.I just set the host header for my site, but when i comes to browse the site the address converts to "http://www.abc.com:85/". As i set the hostname to "abc" and deployed the site on 85 port.

Comment: @Ish If you're using localhost (127.0.0.1) depending on your version of windows you should be able to find the Local Hosts file and modify it. It can be found in `%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` (you may need to make sure you open using administrative rights as `UAC` may stop you editing it otherwise.

Comment: There are two parts @Ish **1.** Set the host header how you want in your IIS website bindings so in your case `www.abc.com`, your IP address this will relate to and the port you want to use if anything other then `80` it will display it on the end of the host header. In your case it will be `http://www.abc.com:85`, if you want it to just be `http://www.abc.com` set the port to `80`. There will be no conflict with any other site because your host header uniquely identifies itself. **2.** Add a line to your Local Host file (see above comment) to associate your IP address to the host header.

Comment: @Ish Added an example based on your requirements.

Comment: @Ish Glad to help. Just felt the other answers didn't solve the underlying issue you had with your approach. The session cookies will not get mixed up now as they will be tied to their own host headers. No browser switching, incognito mode or storing variables in code. Simples. :)

Comment: Yep, this is the awesome solution and best approach to deal this problem. But other solution also have their place, yet not so generic.

Answer (score 0):

Additional option to what @logikal suggest would be adding session variable to identify which port is in use. And act based on value of this variable. And since you using cookies add that value to cookies name as well so browser could differentiate which one to use.

Each instance will have unique identifier based on value of that variable.

Easy to implement in header and basically bullet proof and you do not need to jump from one browser to another.

Comment: *Bulletproof* is not what I would use to describe that scenario.

Comment: Based on what he asked for, it is. Headers solution will work fine except it will not be what he was asking for: running same website on different ports...

Comment: Reading between the lines though you realise that he just wants to run multiple sites on his localhost without conflicting sessions. I'm not saying your solution wouldn't work, it just seems a lot of re-inventing the wheel when IIS gives you the tools to do this out of box without having to write code (which could be buggy) to do in effect the same thing.

Comment: I see lot of questions here got closed just because of that: those require to read between the lines or experts who understand what question all about without clear picture drawn in question. Lets not create discussion. Thanks.